# How to downgrade to older version of Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have in my .gradle folder, a 2.4 folder which is the version of gradle.
I want to downgrade to 2.2.1, because I need to use Gradle plugin 1.0.1.
I already try to change by:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

But this did not solve the issue and I'm still with 2.4 version.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 91):

Change your gradle version in project setting:
If you are using mac,click **File**->**Project structure**,then change gradle version,here:
[image]

And check your **build.gradle** of project,change dependency of gradle,like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19):

I did following steps to downgrade Gradle back to the original version:

- I deleted content of '**.gradle/caches**' folder in user home directory (windows).
- I deleted content of '**.gradle**' folder in my project root.
- I checked that Gradle version is properly set in '**Project**' option of '**Project Structure**' in Android Studio.
- I selected '**Use default gradle wrapper**' option in '**Settings**' in Android Studio, just search for gradle key word to find it.

Probably last step is enough as in my case the path to the new Gradle distribution was hardcoded there under '**Gradle home**' option.

Comment: In my case, I just followed the last suggestion: "I selected 'Use default gradle wrapper' option in 'Settings' in Android Studio, just search for gradle key word to find it."

Comment: selecting 'Use default gradle wrapper' worked for me as well

Answer (score 8):

Got to

> gradle-wrapper.properties

Change the version of the below mentioned distribution (gradle-5.6.4-bin.zip)

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-bin.zip

Answer (score 1):

got it resolved:

uninstall the entire android studio

### uninstalling android with the following commands

```
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*  
rm -Rf ~/.gradle  
rm -Rf ~/.android  
rm -Rf ~/Library/Android*  
rm -Rf /usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/  
rm -Rf /Users/<username>/.tooling/gradle
```

Remove your project and clone it again and then goto `Gradle Scripts` and open `gradle-wrapper.properties` and change the below url which ever version you need

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2-all.zip`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted to downgrade to older version of gradle because my the current version of my Android Studio was Flaming Patch, so it was using gradle 8.0 and I  was running into my problem with my Android project.

So in order to downgrade to older version. I recommend the following:

For example:

1. Uninstall Android Studio Alpha, Beta, Canary or Patch (Flaming Patch in my case which was using gradle 8.0).
2. Go to https://developer.android.com/studio/archive
3. Download a previous stable version (Dolphin for example which uses gradle 7.3.0).
4. That's it.

I recommend this way to downgrade versions instead of using latest version of AS with incompatible gradle versions.

[image]

Comment: You write *"I recommend this way to downgrade versions instead of using latest version of AS with incompatible gradle versions."*. Can you elaborate on this? Why do you recommend this? [Here on the Android Studio download archives page](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases/as-dolphin-release-notes) they actually recommend agains what you write in your answer. What is the problem with downgrading gradle in the latest versions of Android SDK?

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix is to downgrade android gradle in android/build.gradle. Version 4.1.0 seems to cause problems.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

Comment: Everytime you have to fight with Android Studio

Answer (score -1):

For me , I was trying to run the Gradle project but some dependencies has compatibility issues so i had to downgrade it to a lower version.

I updated the gradle version in **gradle-wrapper.properties** with a suitable version.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In simple terms, all new versions create problems before they are finally stable.
I was running mine on old version, when I updated, then problems started. I'm yet to downgrade from v8 to v7.3 and see what happens.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).