# Can't find symbol variable "LocationServices" in GoogleApiClient instance?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-location-services

i am new to GeoFencing and i am trying to add API to the  GoogleApiClient instance.But it is showing error like can't find variable LocationServices.
Here is my code:

```
private void createGoogleApi() {
    Log.d(TAG, "createGoogleApi()");
    if ( googleApiClient == null ) {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
                .addConnectionCallbacks( this )
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener( this )
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
}
```

And my gradle is

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
```

Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="Server_key" />
```

Can you pls look into this.or else you can provide some other docs or links for reference.Thanks

Comment: Check this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40782046/5241603

Answer (score 0):

In gradle add play-services location

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
}
```

once you check all the updates are done in SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing out something like this:

```
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
```

for further reference [see here](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/fused-location-provider-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add below line in your app level build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
```