# Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-appcompat

I am trying to build an application on my real device using Android Studio but it gives me an error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1    .
   Required by:
       MyApplication:app:unspecified
```

The appcompat-v7:24.2.1 is installed and located at `...\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\24.2.1.`

I also put this directory in the "library repository" in file > project structure but the problem was not solved.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please post the code from your gradle?

Comment: I don't know whether it answer your question or not. Take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40782046/5241603

Comment: what is the android version of your real device?

Answer (score 5):

Update your android studio to the latest version.

Comment: Sometimes we need to use old versions to develop to old APIs, latest version does not work for API below 14

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use android latest versions. But you can resolve by replace below code in your `app/build.gradle` file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.2.1"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        ...
}
```

Dependencies as follows:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

Comment: buildToolsVersion "24.2.1" do not exists..
Instead try for "24.0.3" which is actually documented

Comment: @Gagandeep Yes then you can use "24.0.3". And the android.support versions also better to having "24.0.3"

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. update version of build tools and dependences in buyild.gradle(Module)

   ```
   android {
     compileSdkVersion 24
     buildToolsVersion "24.2.1"
     defaultConfig {
     minSdkVersion 19
     targetSdkVersion 24
     ...
   }
   ```

and dependences

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

2. Uses Maven google repository instead of google() in build.gradle(project)

   ```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
   .....

   allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
   }
   ```

**Note:**
Android Studio 4.1.1
Gradle 6.5

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have just used Maven google repository in build.gradle(project) :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Android Studio to the latest version to resolve

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0` in your `app/build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because of your minimal SDK version, and you need to migrate to AndroidX as SDK does not support legacy support components