# android : I have to downgrade my build tool version from 25.0.0 to 19.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am working on library project. Currently my project is running on this version

[image]

But client require this version

[image]

when we change to this version in project structure 
then this error is come

Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.1.0) is too low for project ':projectSample'. Minimum required is 25.0.0

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
}
```

Comment: check your libraries. Must be one of them min sdk version 25.0.0

Comment: [Change your gradle version in project setting:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892760/how-to-downgrade-to-older-version-of-gradle)

Comment: "But client require this version" -- why? Those were replaced years ago. Beyond that, examine the full Gradle Console output to try to get an idea of what exactly is triggering this message.

Comment: Muhammed GÜNEŞ you can  check min sdk is 15

Comment: @hafizatifamin But the `targetSdkVersion` is 25. I would guess this can't be higher than the build tools version.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested practice is to set `compileSdkVersion` to the most recent API level and use the most recent Build Tools. If you need your app to run on older devices, you can set `targetSdkVersion` and `minSdkVersion` to lower values.