# Creating a project with a previous version of gradle in android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am currently learning android with a book called [head first android  2nd edition](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/head-first-android/9781491974049/).

As a reference I am using the [code uploaded by the writer to github](https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid2ndEdition).

I am currently using the latest `andriod studio 3.1` which comes with the latest version of `gradle`.

When I checked out the source code, I discovered that the version of gradle being used is a previous version.

Now my problem is that while practicing on my own, I wanted to create a new project with the same version of gradle, which the *head first android* writer provided.

How can I achieve that ?

PS: my android studio runs faster with the gradle version which the writer provided in his source code.

Answer (score 0):

There already was a question here where you get explained how to change the gradle version, you are using. It's very simple. Just read this [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892760/how-to-downgrade-to-older-version-of-gradle?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)