# Gradle code broken after updating to gradle 6.x variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration() not working

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I defined manifest placeholders for different variants using following code.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
//        def names = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getFlavorName()
    def mergedFlv = variant.getVariantData().getVariantConfiguration().getMergedFlavor()

    mergedFlv.manifestPlaceholders = [pl1: mergedFlv.getApplicationId() + mergedFlv.getApplicationIdSuffix()]
```

It was working well. But I updated to the latest version of Android Studio a week ago and also updated gradle version for this project when Android Studio prompted and the Android Studio throws following error.

```
No signature of method: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData.getVariantConfiguration() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

How do I fix this?

**Update**

I found this class at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/0d498ccf6f91a12c036b382b7ae2b1a809eb2b9d/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/variant/ApplicationVariantData.java

It does not have `getVariantConfiguration()` method. But it is extending `ApkVariantData` class which in turn is extending `BaseVariantData`. `BaseVariantData` has this public method `getVariantConfiguration()`

Thus it should be accessible. I closed and reopened project as well as android studio and tried building project again too... Doesn't seem to work.

Any help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now I downgraded my Android Gradle Plugin Version from `4.0.0` to `3.6.3` and Gradle Version from `6.5.1` to `5.6.4` following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33892937/9640177) answer (method to downgrade) and it worked.

There seems to be problem/bug with Gradle.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may no longer work. See [Android 4.0 Known Issues - Variant Output](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#variant_output)

Try this instead:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
//        def names = variant.getFlavorName()
    def mergedFlv = variant.getMergedFlavor()

    mergedFlv.manifestPlaceholders = [pl1: mergedFlv.getApplicationId() + mergedFlv.getApplicationIdSuffix()]
```

It worked for me.