# Impossilbe to downgrade gradle version during build

Tags: gradle, nativescript, nativescript-vue

As I was trying to provide fixes on our app developed with nativescript-vue 2.4 and nativescript 7.

The situation right now is gradle 7 no longer support some compiler features. For some obscure reason, I am unable to control which gradle version to use for compilation.

[We have found solution for locking the gradle by specifing it in the build.gradle file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892760/how-to-downgrade-to-older-version-of-gradle)

I suspect there is a plugin currently overriding this to use the latest gradle version.

Here is the dependecies at play :

```
      "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.19.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "nativescript-cardview": "3.2.0",
    "nativescript-clipboard": "1.2.0",
    "nativescript-dev-version": "./custom-hooks/version",
    "nativescript-fingerprint-auth": "7.0.2",
    "nativescript-geolocation": "^5.1.0",
    "nativescript-i18n": "0.4.1",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "1.5.1",
    "nativescript-keyboard-toolbar": "1.1.0",
    "nativescript-loading-indicator": "2.5.2",
    "nativescript-local-notifications": "4.2.1",
    "nativescript-lottie": "3.0.3",
    "nativescript-masked-text-field": "4.0.3",
    "nativescript-pager": "11.0.11",
    "nativescript-phone": "3.0.1",
    "nativescript-platform-css": "1.6.10",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "10.6.3",
    "nativescript-preferences": "1.1.2",
    "nativescript-secure-storage": "2.6.0",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "1.0.6",
    "nativescript-toasty": "2.0.1",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "8.2.0",
    "nativescript-vue": "2.4.0",
    "node-email-validation": "1.0.4",
    "tns-core-modules": "6.5.20",
    "vue-currency-filter": "3.4.3",
    "vue-i18n": "8.16.0",
    "vuex": "3.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "eslint": "3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "11.3.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "2.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "2.7.0",
    "husky": "4.2.3",
    "nativescript": "7.2.1",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "1.5.1",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "2.3.0",
    "node-sass": "4.13.1",
    "prettier": "1.19.1",
    "tns-android": "6.5.3",
    "tns-ios": "6.5.4",
    "vue-loader": "15.9.1"
  },
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Can you share your package.json dependencies?

Comment: @TomG I updated my question with the dependencies. However, I ended up doing the great leap and updated NS7 to NS8. Apart from some replacement of no longer required libraries like axios the update was flawless. Maybe the lesson is convincing your boss to stay to latest with NativeScript is a better investment. ;)