# How can i solve android studio gradle problem in my NEW Macbook M1 Pro chip 14?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

11:13:21 PM: Executing ':app:Test.main()'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Initialization script '/private/var/folders/69/bx79vy654zb3tyf4s26vdyc00000gp/T/Test_main__.gradle' line: 41
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not create task ':app:Test.main()'.
> SourceSet with name 'main' not found.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 85ms

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
11:13:21 PM: Execution finished ':app:Test.main()'.

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems to indicate the problem has nothing to do with your *"NEW Macbook M1 Pro chip 14"*. Instead it says that your build uses deprecated features.

Have you tried installing an older gradle version in Android Studio? You might be able to run it then.

Comment: No, I didn't try. How can I do it? My older projects are not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33892760/how-to-downgrade-to-older-version-of-gradle

Answer (score 0):

I use build types with different flavors. They must be inserted outside the Android tag with the new version of the gradle.
Copy and Paste your build.gradle file